# Inaccurate coordinates on account fields

Tags: geolocation

I'm experiencing inaccuracies on the longitude and latitude on the built in longitude and latitude fields in the account addresses. The inaccuracy is not just a rounding error, the results puts the address a few cities away. I've validated the address in google maps  and confirmed the coordinates are wrong. Any idea?

```
ShippingLatitude
ShippingLongitude    
BillingLatitude
BillingLongitude
```

[UPDATE] This is not the address but it is an example I was able to find. If you put the coordinates in google maps you will be able to confirm they are off.

[image]

```
Instance: NA5
```

Comment: It's hard to see this question staying open as written. Can you please [edit] your post to add *some* sort of evidence?

Comment: Are you able to share the address in question?

Comment: @DanielBallinger Please see update.

Comment: the field in your post indicates `ShippingLatitude` but the screen shot is `BillingLatitude`, when I enter the 84 Charlton Road address above in cs2, I get BillingLatitude 42.061291 that agrees with Google maps

Comment: @cropredy It's happening on both shipping and billing. If you your coordinates match then maybe it is an issue with my instance. Did you maybe change something on the address?

Comment: nope - i entered the address exactly as you had it and the Google maps pointed to the same image.  Note I used this in a Winter 17 sandbox with Data.com Clean licenses

Comment: Has anyone found the answer to this? we are experiencing the same issue,... where by the address entered (shipping) returns the correct map picture/location, but the built in geolocation fields refer to an point on google maps that is 6 kms southwest, in a different suburb, and our ShippingAccuracy field is returning "Zip".???